# Derivative of multiplied vectors and matrix with respect to single variable in vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus

Let *v* be a vector $v = (a + bc_1, ..., a +  bc_n)$. Thus, we can say $v = a1 + bc$, where $1 = (1,..., 1)$ and $c = (c_1,...c_n)$.

Let $M$ be a symmetric and quadratic matrix of proportions $n * n$, which elements we note $m_{ij}$.

What is the derivative with respect to $a$ of $v^TM v$? What is the derivative with respect to $b$ of $v^TM v$?

### Context for the interested

I have tried to optimize the following problem in finance (specifically modern portfolio theory)

min $w^TΣw$ s.t. $w^T1 = 1$, $w^Tμ = μ_*$, $w^Tθ \geq θ_*$, where θ is ESG-score.

The problem is the basic mean-variance optimization with an added θ-inequality. From this problem I reduced it to a simpler form using KKT-conditions, and now use Lagrange multipliers (*a* and *b* in the problem above are the multipliers)  to finally optimize the problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: apply the Leibniz rule $\frac{d}{dx}B(u,v) = B(\frac{du}{dx},v) + B(u,\frac{dv}{dx})$ to the bilinear form $B(u,v) = u^T M v$ and set $u=v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your $b$ is a real parameter (or complex parameter), but in any case you are looking at a vector function of one variable. You can simply expand $v^T M v$ to get a quadratic in $b$ and differentiate in a straightforward manner this quadratic:
$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{db}v^T M v &= \dfrac{d}{db}\left( \alpha^T M \alpha + b(\alpha^T M c + c^T M \alpha) + b^2(c^T M c) \right) \\ 
&= \alpha^T M c + c^T M \alpha + 2b c^T M c
\end{align*}
$$
where $\alpha = a \cdot 1$.

**Alternatively**, as hinted to in the comments: define $B: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ by $B(u,v) = u^T M v$.

This $B$ is a bilinear form, and therefore is of class $C^{\infty}$, with derivative $DB(u,v)(h,k) = B(u,k) + B(h,v)$, i.e.
$$DB(u,v)(h,k) = u^T M k + h^T M v$$
Next, apply the chain rule:
$$\dfrac{d}{db}(v^T M v) = D[B \circ (I,I) \circ (f)](b)$$
where $I$ is the identity map and $f$ is $b \mapsto \alpha + bc$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{db}(v^T M v) &= DB(f(b),f(b))(f'(b),f'(b)) \\ &= DB(\alpha + bc, \alpha + bc)(c,c) \\
&= (\alpha^T + bc^T)Mc + c^T M(\alpha + bc)  \\
&= \alpha^T Mc + bc^T Mc + c^t M \alpha + b c^TMc \\
&= \alpha^T M c + 2 b c^T M c + c^T M \alpha
\end{align*}$$
Of course this second way of doing it is an overkill, but it helps to think this way when the situation isn't as straightforward.

**Added**: I now noticed that you asked for both the $a$ and $b$ derivatives. To get the $a$ derivative, follow the exact same procedure(s) outlined here.

Comment: Using the quadratic form you employ, I get $\frac{d}{da}\ = 2a\textbf{1}^TM\textbf{1} + b\textbf{1}^TM\textbf{c} + b\textbf{c}^TM\textbf{1}$. But how did you get the quadratic form in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: @mrentscheidung just by expanding! You have to note that operating by vector multiplication on a matrix (whether from the left or the right) is linear, and then it's just a matter of expanding. Apologies, I cannot provide a detailed explanation now because I'm on mobile. I also couldn't check if what you got for $d/da$ is correct, but so long as you're following the method in my answer I think it should be good!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Greek letters for the scalar variables, lowercase Latin for vectors, and uppercase Latin for matrices.

First, calculate the differential of $v$
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\c{c}
\def\O{{\large\cal\Omega}} \def\o{{\tt1}}
v &= \o\a + \c\b \\
dv &= \o\,d\a + c\:d\b \\
}$$
Then the differential of the quadratic form
$$\eqalign{
\O &= v^TMv \\
d\O &= v^TM\,dv + dv^TMv \\
 &= 2v^TM\:dv \\
 &= 2v^TM\,(\o\,d\a + c\:d\b) \\
 &= 2v^TM\o\,d\a \;+\; 2v^TMc\,d\b \\
}$$
From this, one can identify the desired derivatives
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d\O}{d\a} &= 2v^TM\o, \qquad
\frac{d\O}{d\b} = 2v^TMc \\
}$$